# Semantic HTML element for a book content?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup, semantic-html

I would like to put the entire book content (all the text, chapters etc.) into an HTML file.

**Is there any semantic HTML element that I can use to wrap the text from the book?**

<del>Let's say for example that I want to make a website where someone can read copyright-free books. How should I manage the book content? Using the simple paragraph `<p>` or there is a more specific element? Does `<article>` fit these requirements?</del>

Does the code below have a sense in a semantic way? Or there is a better way to do it.

```
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>BOOK TITLE</h1>
            <p>Story by AUTOHOR NAME</p>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h2>CHAPTER ONE</h2>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>CHAPTER TWO</h2>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
            <p>PART Of THE TEXT...</p>
        </section>
        <!-- more SECTION elements -->
    </article>
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: This code looks great from a semantics standpoint.

Comment: Agree with @Sean. This is semantically clean, and fits the model of the content.

Comment: Thank you Sean and Mike Hofer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of preference, but you can use the `<section>` and `<article>` elements that come with HTML5.

`<section>` and `<article>` are similar to each other. You can decide which one to use by:

1- An article is intended to be independently distributed or reusable.

2- A section is a thematic grouping of content.

```
<section>
   <p>Stories</p>
   <section>
     <article>Story 1</article>
     <article>Story 2</article>
     <article>Story 3</article>
   </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question a bit, to clarify it better. Appreciate it if you can check it out.

Comment: "Stories" should be a heading, not a paragraph. And the articles should not be wrapped in a bounding section element.